# Remotely connecting to postgresql server works from my computer does not work from hosting provider's

Tags: postgresql

There is a PostgreSQL server on a Windows computer that I need to access remotely. It's not on the local network. I'm trying to connect to it with pg_pconnect. I have an AMP stack with PHP 7.1.23 on my local Mac computer and I can connect to it just fine. (The connection works, I can make queries, etc.) When I upload the same script to a hosting provider (LAMP stack with PHP 7.1.22) the script does not work anymore.

> Warning:  pg_pconnect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: could not connect to server: Connection refused
>       Is the server running on host "x.x.x.x" and accepting
>       TCP/IP connections on port 5432? in /path/to/my-script on line 42

I would think that the SQL server does not allow remote connections if it didn't allow the connection from my computer either. But to that server both connections would be remote, right? So how can it allow one and not allow the other?

Comment: Some basic questions... assuming you're using an ip address as host name, is it a public IP which the remote machine can access? If so, given that the connection is being made from something outside your local network, is any firewall to your network configured to allow access to port 5432? Is the pg server's local windows firewall configured to allow the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that the hosting provider had to whitelist the IP address first. That's why it didn't work.